# Отображение webBrowser

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Добрый день, не могу найти  в webBrowser возможность настройки отображения папок, файлов и колонок при навигации по локальному диску, есть ли такая возможность вообще

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Если речь про WinForms...**

Вам точно нужен `WebBrowser`? Если да, то посмотрите [сюда](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/b47bdce9-7360-43d1-900a-99ea9cb49554/webbrowser-to-view-local-files?forum=winforms). `WebBrowser` -- это ActiveX компонент, поэтому придется извратиться.

Если же вам нужна просто функциональность Эксплорера, используйте [`ListView`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview(v=vs.80).aspx). В MSDN есть хороший [мануал](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171645(VS.80).aspx) на эту тему.

Comment: можно воспользоваться и ListView но я ищу лучшие решение, возможности WebBrowser намного серьезней да в перспективе подлежат расширению, будем извращаться, спасибо за ссылки

Comment: @SergD29 удачи!